# Scala Spark - convert DenseVector with nulls to SparseVector

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have quite big vector of around 20k Doubles most of which are null. Is it possible to convert it to the SparseVector and how?

Answer (score 2):

`org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector` provides `toSparse` and `toDense` methods which can be used to change the representation.

However it shouldn't possible to have `Vector` (or any other collection like object) of `scala.Double` containing `nulls` in the first place.

Comment: Thank you. What about 0s - is it possible to make a SparseVector from an Array treating 0s as empty values?